# Why does GCC define only __INT8_MAX__ and not __INT8_MIN__?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, stdint

GCC's predefined macro includes `__INT8_MAX__` but not `__INT8_MIN__`.

`INT8_MIN` is defined in `stdint.h` with `(-__INT8_MAX - 1)`.

Does GCC assume that the system is in two's complement? I think `(INT8_MAX +1)` is a better way to define `INT8_MIN` since it'll work in both 1's complement system and 2's comlement system, and the best is compiler-provided `__INT8_MIN__`.

Why doesn't gcc provide `__INT8_MIN__`?

I don't actually have any system not using two's complement so I don't get any trouble using it but I'm just curious.

Comment: Why does it matter what standard library implementations use internally? That's none of your business. Use the [standard macros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) and be done with it? Don't spell out anything that contains two consecutive underscores.

Comment: If you're in C++ use [std::numeric_limits](http://blog.hostilefork.com/modern-cpp-or-modern-art/).

Comment: @KerrekSB Because I'm writing the standard header for my kernel :)

Comment: @kukyakya: I'm not sure how that matters. The free-standing environment guaranteed by the C++ standard covers type range limits (Table 16); no need to roll your own.

Comment: @KerrekSB libstdc++'s `cstdint` includes `stdint.h`, which is not part of gcc but libc. There is `stdint.h` in libstdc++, but it actually `#include_next <stdint.h>`. I'm writing a self-C++-hosted kernel so I think I have no other way but to roll my own.

Comment: __INT8_MAX__+1 is a bad idea since overflow is not defined for signed integers.

Comment: Yes, gcc assumes 2's complement.

Comment: @Otomo: While that's true from a Standards perspective, it's irrelevant to the GCC/libc boundary because according to the Standard both are part of the same implementation. And it's no problem that one part of the implementation makes assumptions about another part.